# Strange response when answering a y or Y, n or N

Tags: c++, xor

When I placed my loop I wanted to place a cin in a different function and have it return based on the bool provided. I thought I did it right, but it's returning something weird. It doesn't look like an underflow or overflow. It returns 00DB1078, which kind of looks like a hex to me. Anyways I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or where to start to research this kind of problem. Here is my code.

```
    cout << "That was fun! Would you like to play again? ";
getline(cin, Response);
// cout << "Is it y? " << (Response[0] == 'y' || Response [0] =='Y');
if
    (Response[0] == 'y' || Response[0] == 'Y')
    return true;
else if (Response[0] == 'n' || Response[0] == 'N')
    return false;
```

This is where it calls to.

```
    int main()
{
// do while (Response == 1)
PrintIntro();
PlayGame();
AskToPlayAgain();
cout << "You said" << AskToPlayAgain;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't see where are you printing thst hex. Please provide the code part that shows your result.

Comment: Firstly, extract a [mcve]. Without it, your question is off-topic and it also helps you find the error. Then, format your code consistently, since you want others to read it.

Comment: Best guess: you printed the function address instead of calling it -- e.g. you wrote `cout << functionname;` instead of `cout << functionname();`

Comment: I placed where it calls to now.

Comment: `AskToPlayAgain` is a function. `cout << AskToPlayAgain;` prints the function, or at least the address of the function.

Comment: Ulrich and immibis got it! I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to check to see if the function was returning properly is flawed. To fix it place () at the end of the function name.

Comment: It totally answers the question, and while the other answer is more detailed, this one was first. Voted to leave open.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are *printing the address of the function `AskToPlayAgain`* and not the value returned by *function `AskToPlayAgain`*.

To correct this issue change line `cout << "You said" << AskToPlayAgain;` to `cout << "You said" << AskToPlayAgain();`

Following is corrected code. You can [see it working here](https://ideone.com/0hX3en):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


bool AskToPlayAgain()
{
    string Response;
    cout << "That was fun! Would you like to play again? ";
    getline(cin, Response);
    // cout << "Is it y? " << (Response[0] == 'y' || Response [0] =='Y');
    if
        (Response[0] == 'y' || Response[0] == 'Y')
        return true;
    else if (Response[0] == 'n' || Response[0] == 'N')
        return false;
    //For other cases when 1st character is not 'n' or 'N' or 'y' or 'Y'
    return false;
}

int main() {
    // do while (Response == 1)
    //PrintIntro();
    //PlayGame();
    //AskToPlayAgain();
    cout << "You said " << AskToPlayAgain();
    return 0;
}
```